# C++11 - Range-based for loop on a two-dimensional map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, multidimensional-array, auto

I have a two-dimensional map that I declared like that :

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, Objective>> objectives_t;
```

I want to save the content of this 2d map into a file.

So I tried something like that, inspired by some code I found on the web :

```
for (auto const &subject : m_objectives) {
    for (auto const &objective : m_objectives[subject.first]) {
        //Print the objective
    }
}
```

But of course, this doesn't work. How should I do that ? I'm not really sure what are subject and objective (are they some iterators ?).

On the second line, I get :

```
error: passing 'const objectives_t {aka const std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Objective> >}' as 'this' argument of 'std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = std::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Objective>; _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Obj|
```

Comment: `for (auto const &objective : subject.second)`

Comment: You've dug too deep. First understand a simple `map<int, int>` and make sure you can write range-based loops to iterate over it.

Comment: Maybe figure out the syntax and semantics of the range based loop instead of trying out random  code.

Comment: And understand how `std::map` works too.

Comment: @juanchopanza none of the code above incorrectly uses a ranged based for loop.  The misunderstanding comes from bad use of `map`, not ranged based for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your outter loop is correct. But the inner should be iterating over `subject.second`

```
for (auto const &subject : m_objectives) {
    for (auto const &objective : subject.second) {
        // print out objective.second
    }
}
```

This is because after the first range-based for loop, `subject` has type

```
std::pair<const std::string, std::map<std::string, Objective>> const&
```

So each item is

```
subject.first    // std::string
subject.second   // std::map<std::string, Objective>
```

Then when you iterate over `subject.second`, your `objective` is now a

```
std::pair<const std::string, Objective> const&
```

So again to pull apart the elements

```
objective.first    // std::string
objective.second   // Objective
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Tkank you. But I don't understand why my version doesn't work : m_objectives[subject.first] is equal at subject.second no?

Comment: @Bobog To use a nested map, first you need to understand how a map works.

Comment: @Bobog yes, but 1. you already performed the work needed to locate the value, there's no point in doing it twice ; 2. you should use `map.at(key)` on `const` maps, because `map[key]` adds a default-constructed value if the key doesn't exist, and is thus non-`const`.

Comment: @Bobog The thing that is `const` here is presumably the method containing this for-loop

Comment: Minor nitpick: `std::string` should actually be `const std::string` everywhere in this answer (as that is how map values are typed: `std::pair<const Key, Value>`).

Comment: This is correct, but does not explain why the OP's solution doesn't work.  @Bobog you are correct in asking for that information.

Answer (score 0):

`m_objectives` is `const` in the above code.

`operator[]` doesn't work on `const` maps, because it is defined to modify the map if the key is not found.

So that is what your error is.  Note that if it somehow modified the map, the outer loop would be screwed up, so the map being const was somewhat fortunate.  As you have noted, it wouldn't actually modify it in this case (as you are feeding it keys back from itself).

The `[]` would be inefficient, regardless, as it generates an extra map lookup, when you have the value portion right there.

The fix is simple:

```
for (auto const &subject : m_objectives) {
  for (auto const &objective : subject.second) {
    //Print the objective
  }
}
```

which is both correct (in that it doesn't use `[]` on a `const map`), and faster (in that if you un-`const`-ified the `map` `m_objectives` somehow, using `[]` while iterating over the map is both inefficient and error-prone).